# Seaborn order boxplots for each x label

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have this script to create boxplots with seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import os
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Proxima Nova'

measure = 'balanced_accuracies'
n_runs = 5
runs = [f'run {i+1}' for i in range(n_runs)]

directory = os.getcwd()
csv_dir = os.path.join(directory, f'{measure}_combined_cleaned.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(csv_dir)

melted_data = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['model', 'noise'],
                      value_vars=runs,
                      var_name='run', value_name=f'{measure}')

gaussian_data = melted_data[melted_data['noise'].str.contains('gaussian|original')]
speckle_data = melted_data[melted_data['noise'].str.contains('speckle|original')]
salt_and_pepper_data = melted_data[melted_data['noise'].str.contains('salt & pepper|original')]


def plot(data, title, ax, exclude_from_legend=None):
    sns.boxplot(x='noise', y=f'{measure}', hue='model', data=data, palette=palette, ax=ax, order=model_order)
    ax.set_title(title, fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel(f'{measure}'.replace('_', ' '), fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xlabel('noise', fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)

    loc = 'upper left' if measure == 'ece' else 'upper right'

    if measure == 'ece':
        ax.set_ylabel('expected calibration error', fontweight='bold')

    else:
        ax.set_ylabel(f'{measure}'.replace('_', ' '), fontweight='bold')

    if exclude_from_legend:
        handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        handles = [h for h, l in zip(handles, labels) if l not in exclude_from_legend]
        labels = [l for l in labels if l not in exclude_from_legend]
        ax.legend(handles, labels, loc=loc)

    else:
        ax.legend(loc=loc)

    ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', which='major', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 20))


palette = {
    'Dream On': '#FFF5BA',
    'Dream On + SDA': '#FFE494',
    'Dream On (no interpolation)': '#FFD36E',
    'standard data augmentation': '#B2E0FA',
    'simple mixup': '#7CCBF5',
    'manifold mixup': '#46B5F0',
    'vanilla': '#3DC2A2',
    'radiologists': '#FFA39E'
}

model_order = ['Dream On', 'Dream On + SDA', 'Dream On (no interpolation)', 'standard data augmentation', 'simple mixup', 'manifold mixup', 'vanilla', 'radiologists']

    plot(gaussian_data, 'balanced accuracy vs. gaussian noise', axes[0])
    plot(speckle_data, 'balanced accuracy vs. speckle noise', axes[1], exclude_from_legend=['radiologists'])
    plot(salt_and_pepper_data, 'balanced accuracy vs. salt & pepper noise', axes[2], exclude_from_legend=['radiologists'])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

with PdfPages(f'boxplot_{measure}_cleaned.pdf') as pdf:
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

which produces this plot:
[image: plot]

However, I would like to order the boxplots separately for each x-label (e.g. gaussian 1) by the respective median of each boxplot. Is this possible? I tried passing a custom order in sns.boxplot() but this results in the same order over all noise levels; this is not what I want.
Thankful for any help!

Comment: Of course, sorry, here is the respective .csv: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/av6qgrcv7m6nqt0dox03v/balanced_accuracies_combined_cleaned.csv?rlkey=vyfw7qkjm1rvmjt04t6knxz5x&dl=0

Comment: _I would like to order the boxplots separately for each x-label_ is a bad idea because it makes the data in each plot very difficult to compare. The boxes for each category should be in the same order corresponding to the legend (hue_order).

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The idea is that the colors stay the same but only the order changes. I think that this would make it easier to see which model performs the best in each x category.

Comment: I understand, and that’s a bad visualization practice. When somebody looks at your visualization, it should be easy to read; changing the order of the colors for each category makes your visualization more difficult to interpret.

Comment: What you are asking isn't supported by Seaborn, and it also seems quite cumbersome to manually add.  An alternative could be to create a second plot, where you use `sns.pointplot(..., join=True)` on the medians. Combining both into one plot would probably concentrate too much information.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly supported as an "option" of the seaborn function and I agree with the commenters that it's probably not a good idea, but accomplishing it *with* seaborn isn't too hard. The trick is to use `order` and `hue_order` while calling `boxplot` multiple times.

```
df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

x_var = "color"
hue_var = "cut"
y_var = "carat"

colors = sns.color_palette(n_colors=df[hue_var].nunique())
palette = dict(zip(df[hue_var].unique(), colors))
order = diamonds.groupby(x_var)[y_var].mean().sort_values().index

for x, x_df in df.groupby(x_var):
    hue_order = x_df.groupby(hue_var)[y_var].mean().sort_values().index
    sns.boxplot(
        data=x_df,
        x=x_var, y=y_var, hue=hue_var,
        order=order, hue_order=hue_order,
        palette=palette, legend=x == order[0],
    )
```

[image]